# Updating TextView from another Activity

Tags: java, android, int, adapter, send

I have an Adapter (A ViewHolder) Class, and when a Button is pressed I'd like to update a TextView of the Home() activity, preferrably without launching the activity immediatly.

The code in the Adapter:

```
public class GameViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameViewAdapter.GameViewHolder> {
public static Object OnItemClickListener;
private ArrayList<GameItem> mGameList;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;
public static MyCallback callback;


public GameViewAdapter(ArrayList<GameItem> mGameList, GameViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener mListener, MyCallback callback) {
    this.mGameList = mGameList;
    this.mListener = mListener;
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
public GameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.game_entry, viewGroup, false);
    GameViewHolder GVH = new GameViewHolder(v, mListener);
    return GVH;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameViewHolder gameViewHolder, int position) {
    gameViewHolder.bind(mGameList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mGameList.size();
}

class GameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView itemCover;
    private TextView itemTitle;
    private TextView itemDescription;
    private PopupWindow popupWindow;
    private ImageView popUpImage;
    private TextView PopUpTitle;
    private EditText customAmount;
    private Button add;
    private Button addcustom;
    private Button exit;

    public GameViewHolder(View itemView, GameViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener mListener) {
        super(itemView);
        setupViews(itemView);
    }

    public void bind(final GameItem gameItem) {
        Glide.with(this.itemCover).load(gameItem.getCover()).into(this.itemCover);
        this.itemTitle.setText(gameItem.getTitle());
        this.itemDescription.setText(gameItem.getDescription());
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopUp(itemView, gameItem);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupViews(View itemView) {
        addcustom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addcustom);
        popUpImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.popupimg);
        PopUpTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.popuptitle);
        customAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gameamount);
        itemCover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.GameCover);
        itemTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.GameTitle);
        itemDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.GameAmount);
        exit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exit);
    }

    private void showPopUp(final View itemView, final GameItem gameItem) {
        //Declaration
        final View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(itemView.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final ImageView popupItemCover = popupView.findViewById(R.id.popupimg);
        final TextView popupItemTitle = popupView.findViewById(R.id.popuptitle);
        //Set Data
        Glide.with(popupItemCover).load(gameItem.getCover()).into(popupItemCover);
        popupItemTitle.setText(gameItem.getTitle());
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        //ExitButton
        exit = popupView.findViewById(R.id.exit);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });

        add = popupView.findViewById(R.id.addaverage);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callback.onDataChanged(Integer.valueOf(gameItem.getTime()));
                Toast.makeText(popupView.getContext(), String.valueOf(gameItem.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}

public interface MyCallback {
    void onDataChanged(Integer gameTime);
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onGameClick(int position);
}
}
```

And I have implemented this in the Main Activity:

```
   public void onDataChanged(int gameTime) {
    // it will fire when you call your callback.onDataChanged(); in your adapter
    // here can change your textview
    GameTime.setText(Integer.valueOf(gameTime));
}
```

}

I've tried to use BroadcastReceiver as well, with no success.

Thank you!

EDIT:

When adding the callback my App crashes with following traceback:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.reogen.gametime.Adapters.GameViewAdapter$MyCallback.onDataChanged(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.reogen.gametime.Adapters.GameViewAdapter$GameViewHolder$3.onClick(GameViewAdapter.java:127)
```

Line 127 is: `callback.onDataChanged(Integer.valueOf(gameItem.getTime()));`

Comment: Always add the stacktrace to your question when you are reporting that your app crashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to pass Data from an Adapter to the Main Activity from a OnClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348565/android-how-to-pass-data-from-an-adapter-to-the-main-activity-from-a-onclicklis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create observable like:

in your Adapter create:

```
public interface IMyCallback {
    void onDataChanged(int gameTime);
}
```

Global field in Adapter:

```
private IMyCallback callback
```

Inside constructor of Adapter

```
public MyAdapter(... , IMyCallback callback) {
    ...
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

Now your activity make implements IMyCallback and override method onDataChanged.
And when you create your adapter send as callback `YourActivity.this`.

finnaly you need to make like:

```
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    callback.onDataChanged(Integer.valueOf(gameItem.getTime()));
                }
```

after this call you will get update in your override method onDataChanged in your activity class. enjoy

------------ Update -----------
in your activity, when you will implements interface you will get method like

```
     @Override
    public void onDataChanged(int gameTime) {
        // it will fire when you call your callback.onDataChanged(); in your adapter
        // here can change your textview
        textview.setText(String.valueOf(gameTime));
    }
```

Comment: Good answer. For future reference: if you want to enforce a callback then mark the field as final. If the callback is optional then add the @Nullable annotation so that when converting to Kotlin it correctly becomes nullable.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I think I'm close to achieving what I want, but I don't really understand how I update the TextView in the Main Activity. How exactly do I have to get the callback in the Activity? I've understood what happends in the Adapter tho, so I'm very thankful.

Comment: @ShadeReogen I updated my answer to be more correctly, take a look.

Comment: It crashed, I updated the question with the error. Btw thank you so much for trying to help me

Comment: @ShadeReogen your callback is null for some reason.  check if you make `this.callback = callback;` inside constructor and check if you send to there your activity.

Comment: still null, I'll let you know :)

Comment: you need to post full code now of activity and adapter.

Comment: I posted the full code of the Adapter, since it's where the error is caused

Comment: @ShadeReogen remove static from here `public static MyCallback callback;`, and post part of code were you create new  GameViewAdapter in your activity.

Comment: Actually, the GameViewAdapter is created in a Fragment, but everything works there. I want to send the int to a diffrent activity that has nothing to do with the Adapter. Do I need to invoke it there as well?

Comment: This activity is running or you need to start it?

Comment: I suppose it's running since it's he only activity. I only have Fragments besides that.

Comment: show how you create adapter in your fragment. basically the problem is that you wont get callback on your activity if you send fragment as callback. what you need to do that create some function in your adapter like `registerCallback(MyCallback callback)  { this.callback = callback; }` and call it from activity when the adapter was created.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me out a lot!